# Subversion to ignore certain directories and files

Tags: svn, freebsd

Hi Im using subversion on a freebsd machine.

With a project I have a couple of directories such as cache and a tmp folder used by Smarty. How do I exclude these folders from being committed ever?
Also .project files from Eclipse is always added to the list to be commited. Can I also ignore that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) might give you some insight.

Answer (score 3):

Use the svn:ignore property like this:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore ./some_path
```

It will open a text editor where you can specify a pattern (allowing * as a wildcard) of files to ignore.

If you use a GUI client for SVN or an IDE plugin, it should also allow you to ignore resources.

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions for that.

The first one is (as suggested by Frank) to look into the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) (more recent link) for a repository-specific solution, basically the idea is to add `svn:ignore` properties to directories that will ignore file patterns. This is local in your database, and will be ignored anywhere a checkout is made.

The second one is to [globally ignore some patterns](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config) for one user with `global-ignores`. You can edit your Subversion client configuration file (its location depends on the platform - on Windows you can conveniently access it through TortoiseSVN menu). This is global for all the databases for one user on one machine.